# How to change color of an asterisk symbol in ng-required

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material. I want select box as required. After using ng-required the select box's label is showing an asterisk symbol which is grey color. I want this asterisk symbol as red color. But i can not fix it. thanks

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
    <label>Favorite Color</label>
    <md-select name="favoriteColor" ng-model="favoriteColor" required>
      <md-option value="red">Red</md-option>
      <md-option value="blue">Blue</md-option>
      <md-option value="green">Green</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CSS rule :

```
md-select .md-select-value span:first-child:after {
  color:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  by adding this css:

```
md-input-container.md-default-theme:not(.md-input-focused):not(.md-input-invalid) label.md-required:after, md-input-container:not(.md-input-focused):not(.md-input-invalid) label.md-required:after {
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but it does not work in select box. it works only for input ng-required.